# Javascript Angular 4 Adding Assets folder with multiple fonts, js and css files

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have created a new Angular-cli project which uses angular 4.

The current structure is:

```
root
  | 
  -- src
      |
      --- app
      --- assets
      --- environments
```

From a static html project I created I have n assets folder with css, fonts, and js folders and files which I want to integrate into this angular 4 new project.

How do I got about doing this?